# SQL Server - summing values in one column based on common value in another column

Tags: sql, join, merge, duplicates

I have a temp table after some item name remapping that looks like this:

```
Item   | Count
Apple  | 3
Apple  | 2
Orange | 4
```

that I want to condense into this:

```
Item   | Count
Apple  | 5
Orange | 4
```

My attempt so far using self join is this..

```
SELECT rowone.item, rowone.count, rowtwo.count
FROM temp as rowone LEFT JOIN
temp as rowtwo on rowone.item = rowtwo.item and rowone.count <> rowtwo.count
```

Which gives me

```
Item   | Count | Count
Apple  | 3     | 2
Apple  | 2     | 3 
Orange | 4
```

How can I add the counts for the apples and remove the extra row?

Comment: You should just use `group by`.  And then study SQL a bit more so you have some idea of what you are doing.

Comment: `SELECT t.item, SUM(t.count) AS Count FROM temp as t GROUP BY t.item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT item, sum(count) 'Count'
FROM temp
group by item
```